# HowI can fixed the gallery vertically middle for all resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

recently I have implemented gallery, client say that gallery should be vertically middle for all resolution, so please suggest  me "How can I fixed the gallery vertically middle for all resolution.

Comment: `(screenHeight-GalleryHeight)/2`

Answer (score 1):

Your best choice would be to use some jQuery plugin to center the container, that needs to be in the middle. Yes you can do it with CSS, but thats only, when the element is with a static height. jQuery calculates the height of the element on the fly, there for no need for static heights :)

I'll give you a link for a simple centering plugin:

**[Simple Vertical Align Plugin for jQuery](http://www.seodenver.com/simple-vertical-align-plugin-for-jquery/)**

**Code:**

```
(function ($) {
// VERTICALLY ALIGN FUNCTION
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
    var ah = $(this).height();
    var ph = $(this).parent().height();
    var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
    $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

**How to call it:**

```
$('#example p').vAlign();
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it , if it will happened it will pleasure for me